# Multiple dimensions on indexof array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Anyone can help, how can I declare this type of array in c++??

{2, {3, 4}, {5, {6, 76, 5, {3, 4, 6}}}}

Is c++ support this type of declaration?? if yes then how can we declare it.

Comment: You ask about HOW, but more important is WHAT do you want to model. Can you explain that? Because maybe arrays/vector's are NOT the best approach anyway

Comment: In C++ all items of an array must have the same type.

Comment: @user253751: Luckily there's `std::variant` to make everything of the same type. See my awesome answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It weren't C++ if you couldn't do it.
Before you go down this hell, maybe you think about why you need this structure. Maybe tell us what you want to achieve before introducing such a monster. I'm pretty sure that this code will not survive a code review.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <variant>

int main() {
    std::array< 
        std::variant<
            int, 
            std::array<int, 2>, 
            std::array<
                std::variant<
                    int, 
                    std::array< 
                        std::variant <
                            int, 
                            std::array<int, 3> 
                        >
                    ,4>
                >
            ,2>
        >
        ,3> 
    holy
         {2, 
         std::array<int,2>{3, 4}, 
         std::array<
                std::variant<
                    int, 
                    std::array< 
                        std::variant <
                            int,
                            std::array<int, 3>
                        >
                    ,4>
                >
            ,2>
            {5, 
            std::array< 
                        std::variant <
                            int, 
                            std::array<int, 3> 
                        >
                    ,4>
                    {6, 76, 5, std::array<int, 3>{3, 4, 6}}
            }
         };
    std::cout << std::get<0>(holy[0]); // 2
    std::cout << std::get<1>(holy[1])[0]; // 3
    std::cout << std::get<1>(holy[1])[1]; // 4
    std::cout << std::get<0>(std::get<0>(std::get<2>(holy[2]))); // 5
}
```

<sub>[Try it on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MPEMWKv6z) and
[How it looks with 1 statement per line](https://godbolt.org/z/KrG3nejMP)</sub>

Comment: "I'm pretty sure that this code will not survive a code review." it didn't ;)

Answer (score 2):

The above given initializer list cannot be used for a nested array.

If you wanted to use it for a nested 4d array, then you would need to add more brackets.

You defined a structure.

And this can be modelled like below:

```
#include <vector>

struct I1 {
    int i1, i2, i3;
    std::vector<int> v1;
};
struct I2 {
    int i2;
    I1 i1;
};
struct I3 {
    int i3;
    std::vector<int> v3;
    I2 i2;
};

int main() {
    I3 i3{ 2, { 3, 4 }, { 5, {6, 76, 5, {3, 4, 6}} } };
}
```

My strong guess is, that this will not answer your question. Therefore, it would be important to get more information on what you want to achieve.